# Private Beta Site: Materials Modeling

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

If this is off-topic, I can take it down, but I think its valuable to support other science sites in the network.

[Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/) entered private beta at the end of April. The site aims to address research level questions about both the theory, methods, and implementation behind modeling systems ranging from molecules and proteins, to nanoparticles/sheets/tubes and polymers, to crystals and topological materials. Users come from a wide range of disciplines (chemistry, material science, computational science, drug design) and use a wide range of different modeling frameworks (molecular dynamics, electronic structure theory, Markov models/statistical mechanics, fluid dynamics, machine learning). We have already had a few questions that seem to supplement engineering research: [Phase Degradation of Concrete](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/493/how-is-the-phase-degradation-of-concrete-modeled?r=SearchResults), [Development of Solar Cells](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/329/what-has-caused-this-apparent-stagnancy-in-the-development-of-more-efficient-so?r=SearchResults).

The site is coming up on the decision whether it can move to public beta and we would really appreciate your support. If any of the topics above interest you, or you think there is something in the realm of material simulation/computation that could be addressed well there, please consider joining the site and asking/answering/upvoting some questions. We think this site could have real value to the scientific community and it has already attracted a healthy amount of attention from experts across different fields, but we need the SE network clearly sees that value to ensure that the site is maintained.

For more discussion of the scope of the site: [Topics](https://materials.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here), [Distinguishing Features](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29831/how-can-this-proposal-be-clearly-distinguished-from-chemistry-physics-computat/29832#29832)

Comment: This post is fine. I'll give it a feature tag so that more people see it for a while.

Comment: The site has officially moved to Public Beta! Thank you all for your support!